# Most common format & good practice for 3D models for a placeholder in a PC game

Tags: opengl, 3d, models, format

I'm soon starting programming my first 3D game in OpenGL, C++, for PC. It's going to be a top-down space-based game.

Early on I want to create basic placeholder 3D models for my objects, and then in later stages (if I prove able to write C++ game mechanics successfully...) I'll collaborate with / employ a 3D model artist for the full textured models.

What's the best format to create these placeholders in for optimum integration later on?

Any particular advice for how to program it from the start to make it easier to work with the artist later on?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that [wavefront](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) is the best one to start with. The .obj layout can be exported from almost every editor out there and is really easy to use(Read/write/modify).

The wavefront format is also easy to build upon and to get into a even better suited for your own needing later on, but when you start doing custom adds to it, you are going to need a special exporter from the artists editor.

There is also an awesome library called [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) that will handle most of the different format loading for you, so you can focus on just hooking it with vertexs instead. Both links are worth a good dig-in-to.